# Comet framework for Django

Tags: django, comet

What is the easiest way to implement HTTP push (comet) on Django?

Are there any existing frameworks?

Simple examples would be great.

Comment: I'm wondering if there are any updated opinions on this question.  Or is orbited still the pajamas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [Oribited](http://www.orbited.org/) -- [see example here](http://www.rkblog.rk.edu.pl/w/p/django-and-comet/) and also [this (No longer available)](http://darkporter.com/blog_files/4.django_orbited.html)

Answer (score 3):

[Beacon](http://beaconpush.com) is also an option. It's a cloud-hosted push service, meaning you don't have to install anything. Supports both WebSockets and traditional long-poll.

Has a [Python client](http://github.com/Jahaja/python-beaconpush) too.

Answer (score 1):

try with this to http://code.google.com/p/django-orbited/